# display variables received with http-post

Tags: php, curl, http-post

I used "curl" to send some variables from my website to a remote URL:

```
$url = "a remote url";
$fields =array( variables );

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);

$output = curl_exec ($ch);


if (!curl_exec($ch)) {
    echo 'An error has occurred: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
else {
    echo 'everything was successful';
}
curl_close ($ch);
echo $output;
```

I'm getting "everything was successful", but I didn't know how to display the received variables from the remote URL.

Can someone tell me how to display variables from "$_POST"?
I want to check whether the variables are correctly sent to the remote URL.

Answer (score 0):

Simple use:

```
print_r( $_POST );
```

Or within your "sending" script show your fields as an array:

```
print_r( $fields );
```

**Lets assume that your CURL response is in plain text:**

```
variable1=value2
variable2=value3
```

**You can stil view your response this way:**

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);

$output = curl_exec ($ch);


if (!curl_exec($ch)) {
    echo 'An error has occurred: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
else {

    $rows = explode("\n", $output);

    for( $i=0;$i<count($rows);$i++ )
    {
      $cols = explode('=', trim($rows[$i]) );
      print_r($cols);
    }
}

curl_close ($ch);
echo $output;
```

Comment: what i really need is how to recover the variables from the second website, and use them to do some other stuff

Comment: Oh, so there is the point. So you need to get a valid dataformat from CURL call. Now you have everything stored in variable $output.. What format of data-exchange are you using? XML/JSON/text-plain? Show us print_r( $output ); and print_r( var_dump($output) );

Comment: i'm sorry i'm may be having some troubles to explain my real need. in fact from my website i'm getting the response correctly. what i need is to connect from the other website ( the one who recieves the post request) and display the variables

Comment: In CURL you're making a request. If the request is POST-based you need to pass post-data through $fields = array('variable1' => 'value1', 'var2' => 'val2'); and set CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS. (This You've alread done with success.) Then CURL_EXEC gives you response data from the remote $url. If you need to work with this response (data), you need to parse it. There is no other option. I can provide you further support if You can show me dumped response data.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42314/discussion-between-vaclav-kusak-and-androidm)